# adding perlin noise to THREE.js r121

Tags: three.js, perlin-noise

I have been struggling with finding a good tutorial to add perlin noise to a newer version of THREE.js. I have found many tutorials and examples but they all seem to break when I add r121 into the mix.

I've tried a great example from Codepen using a script from jeromeetienne.github.io

I've also tried this guys tutorial and file http://www.stephanbaker.com/post/perlinterrain/

I've tried several others and no luck. I am convinced it's due to THREE versions being used. Most of what I can find use an old version of THREE.js. I have forked what others have, and it works with the old version they are using but not the new one.

```
 //land
 let landGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(500,500, 50, 50);
  let landMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
color:'green'
})
land = new THREE.Mesh(landGeo, landMat);
  scene.add(land);
noise.seed(Math.random());
for(let i=1;i<100;i++) {
  for(let j=1;j<100;j++) {
   var value = noise.simplex2(i / 100, j / 100);
    // ... or noise.simplex3 and noise.perlin3:
//    var value = noise.simplex3(i / 100, j / 100, clock);

    landGeo[i][j].r = Math.abs(value) * 256; 
  }
}
```

So does anyone know how  can get some version of perlin noise working? I am trying to creat terrain.

https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/mdEEwqb?editors=0010

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the browser console errors? It should be the first thing you check.
I see the error `Cannot read property '1' of undefined`.
Which tells me that something is wrong with the line `landGeo[i][j].r = Math.abs(value) * 256;`
The vertices are in a single dimension array and are vector objects. I am pretty sure it should be:
`landGeo.vertices[i+j].z = Math.abs(value) * 256;`.

Also, I am not sure you are calling the noise function with the correct parameters, though I could be wrong and you may be wanting it like it is.
`var value = noise.simplex2(i / 100, j / 100);`

Also, you are starting your for loops at 1, `for(let i=1;i<100;i++) {`, I am pretty sure you want to start them at 0. `for(let i=0;i<100;i++) {`

There is always the option of doing the displacement in a shader like this [3d example](https://2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/perlin_noise_3d_vertex.html), only in [2d](https://2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/simplex_noise_2d.html)

Comment: Hey there. I did try changing it to `landGeo.vertices...` but then the error is the same but just changes to that name. It’s the same error I keep getting. I had changed the loops to 1 from 0 because on one the the methods I tried I was getting an error about [0] being undefined. 

I have done direct copy and paste from several tutorials into mine verified, variables and other info matched but I kept getting that error with r121 loaded.

Comment: Please note, "The vertices are in a single dimension array", `landGeo[i][j]` becomes `landGeo.vertices[i+j]`. you must change this and the loops starting at 0 to avoid errors. I changed these in your codepen and the scene rendered.

Comment: Great that takes care of the error and now it renders. Probably a basic js syntax I should know. 

Now I just need to get some noise on my plane. I’ll play with it for a while to see what I can get. Thank you a ton!